# Return matches with preg_match without items with numerical keys

Tags: php, arrays, regex, match, preg-match

```
$str = 'foobar: 2008';

preg_match('/(?P<name>\w+): (?P<digit>\d+)/', $str, $matches);

print_r($matches);

Array
(
    [0] => foobar: 2008
    [name] => foobar
    [1] => foobar
    [digit] => 2008
    [2] => 2008
)
```

I want $matches to contain only 'name' and 'digit' values without deleting the others by iteration.

Is it any faster way? Can preg_match by default return for me only string-type keys ?

Note: the above preg_match is an example. I would like a solution for any inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "simple" way as [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) has no such an option to only output named groups.

If you must remove the items with numerical keys from the array and do not want to use explicit loops you may use this `array_filter` workaround:

```
$str = 'foobar: 2008';
if (preg_match('/(?P<name>\w+): (?P<digit>\d+)/', $str, $matches)) {
    print_r(
      array_filter($matches, function ($key) { return !is_int($key); }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY)
    );
} // => Array ( [name] => foobar [digit] => 2008 )
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/icrJ0)

Comment: Sorry, I've tested and a simple foreach() is faster. I need something faster than foreach().

Comment: @ValentinTanasescu Feel free to test. At any rate, there is no way to prevent `preg_match` from creating duplicate numerical captures for the named groups.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew This is a helpful answer +1